# How to read schema.org markup from a page (using a Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, schema.org

I'm creating a Chrome extension, part of this extension is checking if a page contains Schema.org (Product) Markup data (https://schema.org/Product).

I'm a javascript starter, does anyone have a function that makes it easy to extract Schema.org data from a HTML string or a DOM element?

I found many ways to add schema.org code to a page, but not reading it.

The beste would be to get back a javascript array or object containing all Schema.org data from the page.

Comment: any news?? Interested on this!

Comment: Which schema format are you looking to target: JSON-LD, MIcrodata, RDFa?